# Missing libxmlrpc-c3 dependency while installing Boxee

Tags: installation, boxee

anyone can help me to installing boxee in ubuntu natty 11.04, there is an error 
"Dependency is not satisfiable: **libxmlrpc-c3**"

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the forums, this is a known issue with the version of Boxee which you have downloaded from the vendor's website.

The consensus is that the vendor does update the version of boxee when a new distribution such as Natty is released, but you may have to wait a few days/weeks

Assuming that you are unwilling to wait :-)

There is a workaround to "correct" the dependency that can no longer be satisfied in Natty (i.e. that library in your screenshot).

Open you text editor and save the contents of the the following (thanks to this [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5585977&postcount=4)):

```
#!/bin/bash

EDITOR=gedit

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  echo "Syntax: $0 debfile"
  exit 1
fi

DEBFILE="$1"
TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/deb.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
OUTPUT=`basename "$DEBFILE" .deb`.modfied.deb

if [[ -e "$OUTPUT" ]]; then
  echo "$OUTPUT exists."
  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

dpkg-deb -x "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"
dpkg-deb --control "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN

if [[ ! -e "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control ]]; then
  echo DEBIAN/control not found.

  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

CONTROL="$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control

MOD=`stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"`
$EDITOR "$CONTROL"

if [[ "$MOD" == `stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"` ]]; then
  echo Not modfied.
else
  echo Building new deb...
  dpkg -b "$TMPDIR" "$OUTPUT"
fi

rm -r "$TMPDIR"
```

Save the file as "edit-deb-control.sh" into your Downloads directory.

Open a terminal and type the following

```
cd Downloads

sh edit-deb-control.sh boxee<tab>
```

N.B. press the  key will autocomplete the full file name

This will open a text editor with the contents similar to the screen-shot below

change the value of libxmlrpc-3 found in the file to the value shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Save the file in the text editor and close the file.

This will create (after a while) a new .deb file in the Downloads folder.  You will see the name as boxee...modified.deb

Double click that file in File Manager (nautilus) - it should open the software-center, but this time, the dependencies error should no longer be there.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a tutorial to install boxee on ubuntu 11.10 and solves the dependency problem:
http://lauziere.net/how-to-install-boxee-ubuntu-11.10

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.