# How to make Boxee work on 11.04 and above?

Tags: boxee

I am trying to install [`Boxee`](http://www.boxee.tv) on Ubuntu 11.04 but it was only released for 10.10.

I am looking for a detail step by step guide to install [`Boxee`](http://www.boxee.tv) on any Ubuntu 11.04 or above.

Comment: ... better title than the question I answered... however the answers are very similar :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/43870/missing-libxmlrpc-c3-dependency-while-installing-boxee

Comment: Mine seems a tidy bit simpler but more general! :P Hope this stays, was tested on both 11.04 and 11.10 already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For those who do not know

Boxee support for Windows, Mac and Linux was dropped, there are no more packages available to download from the site.

Source code is [`still available`](http://www.boxee.tv/download/?ver=source) for those brave enough to venture down that path.

(*If you have any further information about Boxee and Boxee releases that might affect this information please drop a comment so I can updated it.*)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [tutorial](http://lauziere.net/how-to-install-boxee-ubuntu-11.10) to install boxee on ubuntu 11.10 and solves the dependency problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.